# value of variable not replacing name of variable when getting an object value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a variable searchingFor which is inputted by the user. When a button is clicked, I want the data of the (user inputted name)'s age to display. However I cannot get this to work:

```
    $('#output').html("object: " + searchingFor +
        "<br> age: " + searchingFor.age );
```

At the end of the code, I need searchingFor.age to get the age of the user inputted age, but instead, it is trying to retrieve the age for the object 'searchingFor'

For example: if the user inputted 'jack', searchingFor would be equal to 'jack' and then the code would retrieve jacks age, and output it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i think you need to read some javascript basics and improve your understanding of javascript before tackling this problem again.

Comment: So basically you are looking for the user to type a string, and that string is the name of an object you already have created? So you already have an object "jack" with the age property? You are looking to call an object dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

From how I interpret your question, you are looking to dynamically reference a predefined variable. If that is a wrong assumption, please let me know.

If that is the case, you can define the objects on the global scope and reference them as so:

```
  var jack = {
    age: "22"
  };
  var sally = {
    age: "25"
  };
  $(function () {
    var searchingFor = "jack";
    console.log(window[searchingFor].age);
  });
```

## However

Putting things on the global scope is not recommended. It would be better for you to create an array of person objects with name, age, etc. properties, iterate over that array and compare the item name to the searchingFor value like so:

```
$(function () {
    var people = [
      {
        name: "jack",
        age: "22"
      },
      {
        name: "sally",
        age: "25"
      }
    ];
    var searchingFor = "jack";
    $.each(people, function (index, element) {
      if (element.name === searchingFor) {
        console.log(element.age);
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

## A better solution

as per @Barmar's comment

```
$(function () {
    var people = {
      jack: {
        age: "22"
      },
      sally: {
        age: "25"
      }
    };
    var searchingFor = "jack";
    console.log(people[searchingFor]);
});
```

Comment: I would recommend that `people` be an object, not an array, and uses the names as the keys. Then you can use `people[searchingFor]`.

Comment: @Barmar Updated my answer with your comments. Good catch!